# Method throws error because file is accessed by another process

Tags: c#, winforms

This function doesn't work because another process is using it.

The function must read the file, do something with it's data and write the result to this file.

```
private void changeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LB2.Visible = true;
        TB2.Visible = true;
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                double maxlen;
                BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Open));
                BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                Find(read, out maxlen);
                while (read.BaseStream.Position < read.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                    double A = read.ReadDouble();
                    if (A > 0)
                    {
                        read.BaseStream.Seek(-8, SeekOrigin.Current);
                        w.Write(Find(read, out maxlen));
                    }
                    else
                        w.Write(A);

                }
                read.BaseStream.Close();
                w.BaseStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Give us the stack-trace/error, please

Comment: It is clear. You try to open the same file  for reading and writing at the same time

Comment: if you are wondering how other applications can read and write to the same file its because they aren't they open on a copy of that file, then save to the real file when needed. you should do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my psychic debugging sense says that it's the **FILE** that's in use

And you're getting the error because you didn't close your `BinaryReader` before you created your `BinaryWriter`

---

instead of this

```
BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Open));
BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create));

...

read.BaseStream.Close();
w.BaseStream.Close();
```

do this

```
BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Open));
...
read.BaseStream.Close();

BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create));
...
w.BaseStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

you seem to be opening the same file twice?

```
 BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Open));
 BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Open));
BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create));
```

Same file. `BinaryWriter` probably encounters the exception, though I'm not entirely sure because you haven't showed us. You need to close your `BinaryReader` before you can do anything else with that file.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this to make sure your streams are getting closed

```
using( BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Open)))
{
   using( BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create)) )
   {
       // CODE HERE
   }
}
```

It sounds like you're getting an exception and you're not closing your streams/readers/writers.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
var fs=new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
BinaryReader read=new BinaryReader(fs);
BinaryWriter w=new BinaryWriter(fs);
```

and remove:

```
w.BaseStream.Close();
```